# Color a glyph in a font using FontForge or similar

Tags: fonts

I have a `woff` font and I would like to make the glyph ✓ green, is it possibile using FontForge or other programs?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Colored glyphs are not supported by the woff format. **OpenType-SVG** is the format you should be looking for. It was standardized in 2016, so older software will most likely not support it.

For more info read https://www.colorfonts.wtf/

Comment: Thanks, I'm gonna see if wordpress supports OpenType-SVG fonts.

Comment: @soundwave The browser would need to support it, not WordPress. But there are better ways of coloring the glyphs, using HTML and CSS.

Comment: Oh I see that chrome doesn't support opetype-svg. Is it possibile to edit the color of all the instances of a character just by using CSS, without the need to create a class and then to place the character inside that class? For example something like `✓ { color: green; }`

Comment: No. You'd need to wrap it in a HTML tag, like `<span class="green">✓</span>`. Or you could use Javascript.

Comment: Ok, I will use shortcodes then, thanks